# Oracle 11gR2 - Expdp Full Database With Exclude Some Table Data

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g, export, datapump

We will migrate our database using datapump.

It will be full database export with exclude some table's datas.

But we want to do a different operation for 2 different tables. We want to export the data of the last 1 year for these 2 tables (let them be named table3 and table4). How can I write a query for this? The parfile I prepared is as follows, which commands should I add for these 2 tables?

```
DUMPFILE=dbname_datefull.dmp
LOGFILE=dbname_datefulllog.log
FULL=Y
DIRECTORY=EXPORT_DATE
EXCLUDE=STATISTICS
EXCLUDE=TABLE_DATA:"= 'table1'"
EXCLUDE=TABLE_DATA:"= 'table2'"
--queryfortable3
--queryfortable4
FLASHBACK_TIME=SYSTIMESTAMP
```

At the same time, does this query slow down the process and is it recommended?

Thank you. Best Regards.

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "migrate" the database?  You do realize,of course, that 11g is looongg out of support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the QUERY clause for those tables, something like this:

```
QUERY=table3:"WHERE date3>=TO_DATE('20190101','YYYYMMDD')",table4:"WHERE date4>=TO_DATE('20190101','YYYYMMDD')"
```

date3 and date4 being the date column of those tables.